# In Android development, is there something similar to the app class in WPF

Tags: java, android

This is a general curiosity question.  WPF (Microsoft's Implementation of XAML) based application have a base class (executable starting point) called App.

Is there something in like this in Android Development?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is `android.app.Application`. However:

- I would not describe it as the "executable starting point". It is a global singleton, initialized as part of process startup, and so it might serve in the same role as a true executable starting point.
- Developers do not need to create a custom `Application` subclass. They *can*, and more complex apps are more likely to do so. By default, your process gets an instance of the stock `Application` class.

Comment: Is it advised to implement functions in this class?

Comment: @BobJ: That depends on who is doing the advising. :-) Personally, I use a custom `Application` for cases where it is uniquely suited, for one-time initialization of things that *always* have to be initialized when the process starts. For example: your crash-logging library (e.g., ACRA). Otherwise, I try to leave `Application` alone.